# firebase functions output(logs) differ from emulator output

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

When I run my my firebase function locally using firebase emulator, it gives some output(logs). but when I deploy it in firebase and see the logs in firebase console it gives different output for same code.
e.x I have a field(workTime) in my document. when I get the value of it, It gives me a timestamp and then I convert it into date using **toDate()** method. The conversion differs from emulator and realtime firebase function log (same timestamp, same code).

Here's the code

```
     let workTime = doc.get('workTime');

     console.log("workTime1 = "+workTime);
     workTime = workTime.toDate();
     console.log("workTime2 = "+workTime);
     workTime = workTime.toString();
     console.log("workTime3 = "+workTime);
     workTime = workTime.substring(0,21);
     console.log("workTime final = "+workTime);
```

Function logs in emulator
[image: Function logs in emulator]

Functions logs in firebase console
[image: Functions logs in firebase console]

The dateTime given by emulator is correct one. but, the date given by realtime firebase function is wrong one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because the deployed Cloud Functions are running in a different timezone than you. If you specifically want Indian time you can try this:

```
const d = Date.now() // Current Timestamp

const timeInIndia = new Date(d + (5.5*60*60*1000)).toISOString()
// Output: "2021-06-24T19:46:44.513Z"
```

You can read more about the `Date` object on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and customize the format of the string.